# Prove that $\langle x,y \mid x^5=y^3=1, x^y =x^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is what I have so far:

Let $F$ be a free group upon $\{x,y\}$. Define a homomorphism $\phi:F \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3$ by $x\phi = 2$, $y\phi = 1$. Then we have $x^y\phi = x^2\phi$, satisfying the relations of our presentation.

Hence by Von Dyck's theorem, there exists an epimorphism $\beta: \langle x,y \mid x^5=y^3=1, x^y \rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3$. Hence $3=|\mathbb{Z}_3| \leq |\langle x,y \mid x^5=y^3=1, x^y \rangle|$.

Now I just need to show $3=|\mathbb{Z}_3| \geq |\langle x,y \mid x^5=y^3=1, x^y \rangle|$ to conclude that $\beta$ is an isomorphism. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the second relation supposed to be $x^y = x^2$?

Comment: Yes indeed, my bad.

Comment: Also $y^2xy^{-2}=x^4$ and $x=y^3xy^{-3}=x^8$ so $x^7=1$ and thus $x=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=y^3xy^{-3}=y^2x^2y^{-2}=y x^4 y^{-1}= x^8 $ Hence $x^7=1$. So $x^2=x^7x^{-5}=1 $. So $yxy^{-1}=x^2=1$ . Hence $x=1 $ . So the concerned group is actually generated by $y$ . Now either $y$ has order $1,2$  or $3$ . When order of $y$ is $1,2$ by relations you can deduce that $y=1$ which shows that concerned group is the trivial group . Hence order of $y$ must be $3$. So it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_3}$

Answer (score 0):

If $x\not = 1$, the map $z \to z^y$ acts nontrivially on $\langle{x\rangle} = \mathbb{Z}_5$, but $\mathbb{Z}_5$ has no automorphism of order exactly $3$. The presentation then becomes the standard one for $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? What is x and what is z? Are they elements of the presented group?

Comment: $z$ is a dummy variable; I'm referring to the map $f(z) = z^y$. The variable $x$ is the one in the problem statement.